# Usercontrol Basic Property Binding

Tags: silverlight

HI,

I have a Silverlight UserControl where I bind the **UserControl.Background** property to a border element within it.  I found an easy way to bind the background like that :

```
<UserControl x:Name="root"
    x:Class="TestProject.MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="Red"  >

   <Border x:Name="brdMain" Background="{Binding Path=Background, ElementName=root }" >
         etc... .... ...
   </Border>
```

The problem with that is when I instanciate my UserControl multiple times.  I get the following error :

```
Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 2028    
Category: ParserError       
Message: The name already exists in the tree: root.     
File:      
Line: 0     
Position: 0
```

So is there any other better way to bind my Usercontrol background property without having to name my UserControl like that : ***x:Name="root"***?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
```

**EDIT:**

Since the above is only valid within WPF (SL only supports TemplatedParent and Self) a varying approach could be taken. You could create a `DependencyProperty` (`propdp` is the IntelliSense snippet in Visual Studio) on the `UserControl` which would set the child `Border.Background` appropriately.

I'm trying to understand why you want to set the `Background` on the `UserControl` though versus simply setting it on the `Border` and leaving the `UserControl` empty from a visual stance; allowing it to be the physical container of the child controls which will represent the visuals.

Comment: Not working... getting the following error : 

the property 'AncestorType' was not found in type RelativeSource

Comment: @danbord Arg...SL doesn't support FindAncestor; let me see if there is another way

Comment: Well I wanted to avoid using a custom DP for that property (actually I am using some other proerties to bind like BorderBrush, BorderThickness and I didn't want to create DP for each of them).

Comment: @danbord Keep in mind if you bind these via a style you can then use TemplatedParent in your binding which is a much easier approach; remember to approach your design slightly different in SL then a WinForms application.

Answer (score 0):

there is ancestor relative binding in Silverlight 5 - http://tonychampion.net/blog/index.php/2011/12/7th-day-of-silverlight-ancestor-relative-source-binding/